# 3D printer not printing

Tags: pla

I’m new to the printing scene and got an Ender 3 Neo Max. I printed a couple of models with no problem, then the filament just stopped dispersing. I figured I had a clog, so I tried to shove something up the nozzle and it wouldn’t go in. I disassembled the piece and took the nozzle off, put a new nozzle on, and the filament still wouldn’t disperse. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry your question was closed. We need more detail. You put a new nozzle, so I assume that was not blocked. Thus it is probably blocked somewhere else. Do you know where it is blocked? Maybe further descriptions and some photos would help. Please [edit] and update your question, and then it could be reopened. Otherwise the answers will just be broad guesses. I would have added an answer myself, suggesting these [tiny "drill bits"](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+printer+drill+bits), but they are only useful for blocked nozzles, which doesn't seem to be the issue as you've replaced it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches I have tried in the past is to heat up the nozzle to a hight temperature ( a little less than 260) for several minutes, and to then see whether you can move filament through the extruder by using the menu to go to Motion, Move Axis, Extruder, 10mm.

If that does not work, I suggest that you turn off the machine, let it cool down, and then take apart the hot end - there are online videos to do so.  It's a bit scary the first time but if I can do it, and I have, so can you.  After taking it apart and separating the hot end from the heating block, see if you can feed filament through the hot end.  Then determine if you can feed filament through the heating block.  If you get stuck, I have found it easier just to buy a new hot end or heating block.  (If you buy a new hot end, I suggest getting a bi-metal heatbreak as it does a better job of separating the heat from the tubing that feeds the filament into the hot end. - Chep has a good video on this on YouTube for the Ender 3 Neo.)

If you haven't found any blockage in the nozzle, heating block, or hot-end, it's possible that the tubing through which the filament flows has been damaged (probably by heat).  If that is the case you want to replace it with capricorn tubing which can stand a higher temperature.  It is also a good idea to replace the heatbreak as discussed above.

If none of these fixes your problem, it maybe that the extruder needs to be replaced, or that the control board is broken and not driving the extruder.

Answer (score 0):

Your printer should have come with a bunch of tools, one of which is a thin wire with a rudimentary handle, and the pointy end stabbed in some foam/polystychrene for protection.  Is that what you tried inserting?

It is a very small hole in the end of the nozzle, and you need it hot else the whole thing is blocked with hard filament.